# Finding unknowns in basic vectors

Tags: vectors

Given that $u = 3i + 2j$  and $v = 2i + \lambda j $ determine $\lambda$ such that:

(a) $u$ and $v$ are at right angles (this means perpendicular I presume?)

(b) $u$ and $v$ are parallel

Whilst working out the first one, I obtained the value of -3 for $\lambda$. However I am not sure whether this is correct and am not quite sure how to tackle question (b) from this exercise.

What I can't seem to grasp is, how on earth does the value of lambda determine whether these points on the XY plane are parallel or not?

Would the multiple of the two vectors result in a 0 for perpendicular vectors? If it indeed so then the shift-cosine of 0 would give us 90 degrees (indeed perpendicular). But what value would the multiple of both of those vectors require to be in order to be parallel?

Comment: **HINT:** If two vectors are perpendicular, then what will their dot product equal? Similarly, if two vectors are parallel, then what will their dot product equal?

Comment: @Mufasa Well, if they're perpendicular than I presume their dot product will be equal to 0, however when parallel, -1 or 1?

Comment: Excuse me, I skipped a few steps when I gave you that answer. Would the multiple of the two vectors result in a 0 for perpendicular vectors? If it indeed so then the shift-cosine of 0 would give us 90 degrees (indeed perpendicular). But what value would the multiple of both of those vectors require to be in order to be parallel?

Comment: @Mufasa - That is indeed what is confusing me haha, I'm having a mental tug of war between 180 degrees or 0 degrees

Comment: I do not *think* so, wouldn't the former be -1 and latter 1?

Comment: Alright let me try that!

Comment: Look at answer given by @Dillon below. For parallel vectors the cross product should be used as he shows.

Comment: @Mufasa - Yea that's what I've been looking at. The cross product has been mentioned in the link you provided however I wasn't aware hat it was required as it isn't something I've done in class and thus disregarded. I'll need to read about that first to understand what he did.

Comment: So in this particular case, the CROSS product must be equal to zero instead? Since that would perpendicular to both vectors? Or am I just overthinking all of this simple stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lambda$ is simply the scalar value of the $\textbf{j}$-component of the vector $\textbf{v}$. The only thing that the question asks of you, is to determine the values of $\lambda$ which will satisfy the conditions in (a) and (b) respectively.

**For a):**

We know that two vectors are perpendicular if the angle between them are $90\unicode{xb0}$. Where can we use this fact? Clearly the DOT PRODUCT must spring to mind, since we know the dot product of two vectors, $u$ and $v$ are given by:

> $$u \cdot v = ||u|| \ ||v|| \ \cos{\theta}$$

Now we know $\theta=$ $90\unicode{xb0}$ and $\cos$($90\unicode{xb0}$)$=0$, so we must have $$u \cdot v = 0$$

We thus need to find $\lambda$ such that
\begin{align}u\cdot v &= 0 \\ \therefore (3)(2)+ (2)(\lambda) &=0 \\ \therefore 2\lambda &= -6 \\ \therefore \lambda &= -3 \end{align}

**For b):**

Two vectors are parallel to one another if their CROSS PRODUCT is zero.

Thus we need to find $\lambda$ such that
\begin{align} u \times v &= 0 \\ \therefore \begin{vmatrix}i & j \\ 3 & 2\\ 2 & \lambda\end{vmatrix} &= 0 \\ \therefore 3\lambda - 4 &= 0 \\ \therefore 3\lambda &= 4 \\
\therefore \lambda &= \frac{4}{3}\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much Dillon, I'm simply trying to understand every corner of the question and answer prior to accepting.

Comment: Which parts do you still feel uncertain about? I will try and edit the answer accordingly to try and explain :)

Comment: Alright thanks again for your edit. I wanted to also ask if the cross-product is still equal to zero in 3-dimensional space? Otherwise I am able to both understand and visualize the scenario in 2-dimensional space fairly well.

Comment: Yes it is still equal to zero in 3-dimensional space :) .

Comment: Awesome great, I can't seem to picture it so in my head but I'll try carefully plotting it down to grasp a stronger idea of the cross product. Thanks a bunch to both you and @Mufasa

Comment: Also, the reason for this also being valid in 3-dimensional space, is because we are using a geometrical interpretation of both the dot product and cross product. This geometrical interpretation can be used for any dimension up until $\mathbb{R}^3$ after that we rely on a more "theoretical" approach, which we do not need to cover right now.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks a lot for the extra info!

Answer (score 1):

The following identity of the dot product is useful

> $$ u.v = ||u||\,||v||\cos(\theta). $$

Comment: I've amended a small part going into a bit more detail as to why my results are slightly confusing me, however I shall add my comment in here to grab your attention directly.

"Would the multiple of the two vectors result in a 0 for perpendicular vectors? If it indeed so then the shift-cosine of 0 would give us 90 degrees (indeed perpendicular). But what value would the multiple of both of those vectors require to be in order to be parallel?"